# Escribir en un fichero .txt de forma continua sin tener que cerrar el descriptor de fichero con C++

Tags: c++, txt

La situación es la siguiente, me encuentro creando un sistema de logs sobre una ejecución de la siguiente forma :

```
remove( "logs-init.txt" );
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("logs-init.txt");
myfile << "LOGS-INIT: Program running.\n";
```

esta parte genera el fichero y prepara la primera linea para escribir. A continuación continua la ejecución del código con nuevas lineas tal que :

```
myfile << "LOGS-INIT: Teach_IN read running.\n";
myfile.flush();
```

Se supone que .flush guarda el buffer de escritura, pero esto no esta ocurriendo y hasta que no llega a  myfile.close(); no se cierra el fichero y se guarda todo.

Lo que quiero que ocurra es que cada vez que se escriba una linea esta se escriba den el .txt de forma que otro programa pueda ir leyendo linea a linea, por tanto el problema que tengo es que con estas funciones hasta que no termina con el .close() no me escribe las lineas y el .flush() debe de cerrar el descriptor porque después de el no me escribe nada.

PD: No es un problema del programa puesto que este al terminar su ejecución tiene todos los logs correctamente escritos. Pero como necesito leerlos durante la ejecución del mismo es por lo que me da problemas.

PD (2) : Es un sistema MIPSEL. WisAP WRT abierto Router WIFI módulo/Junta de MT7628. [enlace de compra](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32791851425.html)

El código que lee el archivo es en LUA:

```
function lines_from(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
    lines = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do 
    lines[#lines + 1] = line
    end
    return lines

--    see if the file exists
function file_exists(file)
    local f = io.open(file, "rb")
    if f then f:close() end
    return f ~= nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> Lo que quiero que ocurra es que cada vez que se escriba una linea esta se escriba den el .txt

No es algo sobre lo que tengamos control. Es el sistema operativo quien tiene control sobre el archivo, no el flujo de datos. Sin embargo, [`std::basic_ofstream::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) fuerza la sincronización del búfer interno del flujo de datos con su salida… en otras palabras, fuerza la escritura; por lo que debería funcionarte.

Si no te funciona hasta que cierras el flujo de datos, seguramente se deba a que el sistema operativo no permite el acceso a los datos del archivo hasta que detecte que dicho archivo deja de estar en uso.

---

#### Editado.

Claramente tu problema está en la lectura de datos, no en la escritura:

```
for line in io.lines(file) do 
lines[#lines + 1] = line
end
```

Por lo que puedo leer en la documentación:

> - **io.lines(optional file name)** − Provides a generic for loop iterator that loops through the file and closes the file in the end, in case the file name is provided or the default file is used and not closed in the end of the loop.

La función `lines` accede a las líneas del archivo secuencialmente y leerá tantas líneas como estén disponibles. Si accedes al archivo antes de que este haya hecho el volcado a disco o si el sistema operativo bloquea el archivo por estar en uso, no leerás el contenido. Por otro lado si escribes quince líneas y mientras lees el archivo desde lua escribes otras quince, sólo te leerá las líneas que estaban disponibles en el momento de la lectura.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta lo que me dices, si cada vez que escribe una linea cierro y luego cuando tenga que escribir lo abro de nuevo debería funcionar no ? osea es la forma mas rápida de dejar sin uso al fichero no ?

Comment: Lo que comentas es una posibilidad, pero todas las operaciones I/O con archivos son varios ordenes de magnitud más lentas que las mismas operaciones en memoria. ¿Puedes añadir a tu pregunta detalles sobre el sistema operativo en el que estás trabajando?

Comment: También ayudaría ver cómo es el código que desde otro proceso lee el archivo.

Comment: he realizado una pequeña prueba abriendo y cerrando por linea y podría llegar a funcionar, sabes como puedes hacer para escribir linea a linea porque lo que ha ocurrido es que se ha quedado solo la ultima escrita.

Comment: lo que dices efectivamente es cierto, pero la cosa es que la llamada de lua de realiza de forma recursiva de modo que si en alguno momento el fichero cambia como se realiza la apertura cada llamada en la siguiente se vería el cambio. Pero muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a PaperBirdMaster por la idea, he conseguido la siguiente función que ha funcionado de forma correcta:

```
void writeNewline(const char fileName [],const char msg []){
   fstream filestr;
   filestr.open (fileName, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
   filestr<<msg<<endl;
   filestr.close();
}
```

Para evitar el problema que el comenta se cierra el descriptor cada vez que se escribe de esta forma se puede ver como se va editando linea por linea. la primera escritura del fichero vale con el modelo que estaba en la pregunta.